# Validate number of columns in .xls file before upload in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, validation, carrierwave

I am uploading .xls file using the CarrierWave Gem in Rails. Before uploading the xls file, I want to validate that the .xls file:

1) contains a certain amount of columns

2) that the first row contains certain headers.

I honestly don't even know where to begin. I know the validations must occur in the model, and I also saw that there is a gem for the validation for csv, but nothing for xls. I just need to be pointed in the correct direction.

Comment: You need to convert your xls to csv and go from there in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [Roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) gem

```
sheet = Roo::Excel.new("./excel_file.xls")

# Get the header
sheet.row(1)

# Number of columns
sheet.last_column
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

For validation just create a method that could the job:

```
def validate(sheet)
  errors = []

  header = sheet.row(1)
  num_of_columns = sheet.last_column

  errors << 'Need headers' unless (ARRAY_OF_NEEDED_HEADERS - header).empty?
  errors << 'Need more columns' if num_of_columns < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS

  errors
end
```

You could create your own validator on the model:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am a new to ROR, so I'm a little lost with how this will be made into a validation.  I saw the rails cast episode but I guess I am confusing myself since I am importing the excel with carrier wave. So I guess my question is - how can I incorporate both the sheet.row(1) and sheet.last_column as a validation in the model? Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @RaymondRuiz-Veve I just updated the answer. If you have more questions it's better to create a new one

Comment: Holly Guacamole! Thank you, you are awesome!

Comment: No worries @RaymondRuiz-Veve! Accept the answer if it solved your problem